# Ajax query not working when file is in a sub directory

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to use the following for a simple database query

```js
$.ajax({
        url: "trackingcodedata.php",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: 'json',
        data:{option:1},
        success: function(data) {
            $('#js-tracking-code').val(data.tracking_code[0].js_tracking_code);
        },
        error: function(){
            console.log("failed");
        }
    });
```

the url works fine in this form. What I really want to do is have the file in a sub directory. And call it the same way.

```js
$.ajax({
        url: "db/trackingcodedata.php",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: 'json',
        data:{option:1},
        success: function(data) {
            $('#js-tracking-code').val(data.tracking_code[0].js_tracking_code);
        },
        error: function(){
            console.log("failed");
        }
    });
```

The second version with the file in the db sub directory gives me a 500 error. The first one works fine. ????

Comment: Try using an absolute path and see if that works to narrow it down.

Comment: doesn't seem to work either way. only works if the file is in the same directory

Comment: Does calling the `db/trackingcodedata.php` file directly from your browser also cause 500 error?

Comment: yes. Same error with direct url. perhaps I have a configuration or permissions issue. I can access js files in a sub and some config files I just can't make an ajax call.

Comment: can you share the content of the php file here? Do you have any includes in it? If you are including files in it, then maybe you need to change the path of your includes when you move the file in the sub-directory

Comment: I did have this

Comment: include 'includes/config.php';
include 'includes/errorlog.php';

Comment: includes are in a subfolder that is different. than the sub the file was in. I tried to put the file in a folder called db which was at the same level as the folder called includes.

Comment: If your file was in root folder and you had this line in it `include 'includes/config.php';` and then you move your file to a sub-folder, you have to edit you `include path`. using same path as before, will generate errors because there will be no such file at that path anymore. let say your absolute path is: `/var/user/wwwroot/` then your include path from root would be `/var/user/wwwroot/includes/config.php`. but if you move your file in `db` filder, then your include would search for this path: `/var/user/wwwroot/db/includes/config.php` which does not exist...